# Class wrapper for data lists

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I need some help building a fluent interface (class wrapper) that allows me to create (and name) a 2D double array from curve sets in a database (in myWell). Ideally, a user could create a 2D double array when executing the following syntax (or something similar):

```
 Double [,] CurveDoubleName = CreateIPmathCurves.CreateCurve(comboBox1.Text).CurveName("NPHIL").Make()
```

Where comboBox1 data comes from a WindowsForm called frmMain. Here's what I have so far:

```
namespace UserProgram
{
        public class CreateIPmathCurve : frmMain, ICanNameCurve, ICanLocateCurve, ICanMakeCurve
        {
        private string _comboBoxName;
        private string _CurveName;
        private string _data;

        // Private constructor - Only allow instantiated functions to create an IP math Curve

        private CreateIPmathCurve()
        { }

        // Instantiating functions

        public static ICanNameCurve CreateCurve()
        {
            return new CreateIPmathCurve();
        }

        // Chaining functions 
        private CreateIPmathCurve(string data) { _data = data; } //private constructor prevents instantiation of your builder

        public ICanLocateCurve SetCurveName(string CurveName)
        {
            _CurveName = CurveName;
            return this; // this allows chaining.
        }

        public ICanMakeCurve SetComboBoxName(string comboBoxName)
        {
            _comboBoxName = comboBoxName;
            return this; // this allows chaining.
        }

        // ending functions

        public DataObject CreateCurveDoublArrayObj(string comboBoxName)
        {
            try
            {

                // User will need to populate comboBox.. example: comboBox1.text
                char[] delimiter = { ':' };
                Curve1inText = comboBoxName;

                string[] crvIn1 = Curve1inText.Split(delimiter);

                string CurveSet = crvIn1[0];
                string Curve = crvIn1[1];

                ICurveSet InCurveSet = myWell.FindCurveSet(CurveSet);
                ICurve InMyCurve = myWell.FindCurve(Curve);

                if (InMyCurve == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You need to input a curve");
                }

                ILogReading[] In = InMyCurve.LogReadings.ToArray();

                double[,] CurveDouble = new double[In.Length, 2];

                int j = 0;

                foreach (ILogReading reading in InMyCurve.LogReadings)
                {
                    CurveDouble[j, 0] = reading.Depth;
                    CurveDouble[j, 1] = reading.Value;
                    j++;
                }

                return new DataObject(CurveDouble);
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error building Double Array\n" + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
                return null;
            }

        }

        public double[,] MakeCurve()
        {
            //this is where CurveName input ("NPHIL") should name the 2D double array listed from dataobject.
            // I receive a "non-invocable member 'DataObject' cannot be used like a method" error....

            _CurveName = DataObject(_comboBoxName);
            return this;

            // I also receive a "cannot implicity convert type UserProgram.CreateIPmathCurve' to 'double [*,*]"... 
        }
    }

    // using interfaces to enforce Fluent Interface grammar -- can't make curve if you don't know the location of curve, etc...
    public interface ICanNameCurve
    {
        ICanLocateCurve SetCurveName(string CurveName);
    }

    public interface ICanLocateCurve
    {
        ICanMakeCurve SetComboBoxName(string comboBoxName);
    }

    public interface ICanMakeCurve
    {
        DataObject CreateCurveDoublArrayObj(string comboBoxName);
    }

}
```

Can you help me create a  CurveName() function that would allow the user to name the dataobject? (I tried a getter-setter accessor, but I don't think I was doing it correctly or am lacking a strong conceptual understanding of how it all works)

Lastly, can you also help me create a Make() function that puts all of this together?

Comment: This is called [*fluent interface*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface). Might be a bit too advanced for a beginner. Why don't you start with normal methods/properties?

Comment: What is the result you want to achieve? A double array consists only of double values. So there is no way to name or locate your curve.

Comment: The DataObject CreateCurveDoubleArray finds the curve from my well database (using comboBox input) and populates a 2D double array called CurveDouble.... I want to assign this new 2D double array to a name (assigned by CurveName). I would like the syntax to be something simple, something similar to the syntax above ( CreateIPmathCurves.CreateCurve(comboBox1.Text).CurveName("NPHIL").Make() )

Answer (score 1):

To build a fluent API, you need to find a way to aggregate all data until your call to `Make`.

A simple way is to write a `Builder`, which holds all data. This builder has setter methods for every configurable field.

The key point here is that each setter method returns the `Builder` object, allowing you to chain calls.

```
public class FluentCurveBuilder
{
    private string _name;
    private string _data;
    private string _color;

    private FluentCurveBuilder(string data) { _data = data; } // private constructor prevents instantiation of your builder

    public FluentCurveBuilder SetName(string name)
    { 
        _name = name; 
        return this; // this allows chaining.
    }       

    public FluentCurveBuilder SetColor(string color)
    { 
        _color = color; 
        return this; // this allows chaining.
    }

    public static FluentCurveBuilder CreateCurve(string data) 
    { 
        return new FluentCurveBuilder(data);
    }

    public Curve Make() 
    {
        // Creation logic goes here
    }
}
```

You now can use the builder to configure your curve.

```
var curve = FluentCurveBuilder.CreateCurve("Data")
                              .SetName("Test")
                              .Make();
```

We have a static `CreateCurve` method, which returns a new builder. All other methods should only store the data in an instance field and return this builder.

In the `Make` method, you now have access to all previous aggregated data and you can construct your `Curve`

Comment: thank you lqon, this has proven to help me move closer towards a workable solution. I've updated my question, and code (above) can you take a look and see what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think I was over analyzing my problem - The simple solution would be to create a method that returns the 2D double array and then assign a name to the object when I invoke the function... so using this:

```
public double [,] CreateIPmathCurve(string comboBoxName)
    {

        string CurveInText = "";
        char[] delimiter = { ':' };
        CurveInText = comboBoxName;

        string[] crvIn = CurveInText.Split(delimiter);

        string CurveSet = crvIn[0];
        string Curve = crvIn[1];

        ICurveSet InCurveSet = myWell.FindCurveSet(CurveSet);
        ICurve InMyCurve = myWell.FindCurve(Curve);

        if (InMyCurve == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You need to input a curve");
        }

        ILogReading[] In = InMyCurve.LogReadings.ToArray();

        double[,] CurveDouble = new double[In.Length, 2];

        int j = 0;

        foreach (ILogReading reading in InMyCurve.LogReadings)
        {
            CurveDouble[j, 0] = reading.Depth;
            CurveDouble[j, 1] = reading.Value;
            j++;
        }

        return CurveDouble;
```

Allows me to create the array with this:

```
double[,] NPHIL = CreateIPmathCurve(comboBox1.Text);
```

Thanks to everyone who helped me in this endeavor!